# How grunt can continue building even grunt-contrib-symlink doesn't find a path

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, symlink

I am new in grunt and I am doing some geek plays.

I was trying grunt-contrib-symlink to create a symlink in /dest/path/ from /origin/path.

I have seen that when /origin/path doesn't exists the grunt proces stops because fails.

Basically I am doing this task.

```
symlink: {
            options: {overwrite: false},
            explicit: {src: '/opt/origin/path',dest: '/opt/dest/path}
    },
```

The point it's that depending on the case, 'src' hope doesn't exists. I expect that exists some way to protect this situation, but I can't find it :(

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily resolve this by defining a new task

```
grunt.registerTask('symlinkIfExists' , function(){
     if ( grunt.file.exists('/opt/origin/path') ){
           grunt.task.run(['symlink:explicit']);
     }
})
```

This will only run the symlink target if the file exists. 
You can construct a more generic solution. if required I will try to add it.